# Why is ampersand used in front of these variables?

Tags: c, pointers, ampersand

I found the following sample code, demonstrating the use of `sscanf()` on [TutorialPoints](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int day, year;
   char weekday[20], month[20], dtm[100];

   strcpy( dtm, "Saturday March 25 1989" );
   sscanf( dtm, "%s %s %d  %d", weekday, month, &day, &year );

   printf("%s %d, %d = %s\n", month, day, year, weekday );

   return(0);
}
```

I'm confused about the use of the ampersand in `&day`, `&year`. 
From what I've read, the ampersand is used in this manner on a pointer variable in order to say "don't change where the pointer is pointing to but rather change the value at the address the pointer is already pointing to".

Here it's funny though, because `day` and `year` are not pointers. They are just simple `ints`. Why can't it be written as:

```
...
 sscanf( dtm, "%s %s %d  %d", weekday, month, day, year );
...
```

?

Comment: time to read a basic C tutorial...

Comment: Hint: What are the arguments for `scanf`?

Comment: Because without the `&`s they're pass-by-value. Scanf needs to write to them, so it needs a reference to them that it can write to i.e. a pointer.

Comment: And this bit sounds wrong: "From what I've read, the ampersand is used in this manner on a pointer variable in order to say "don't change where the pointer is pointing to but rather change the value at the address the pointer is already pointing to".  No: the value at the address is `*pointer`. `&pointer` is a pointer-to-a-pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The ampersand means "address of". So what you're doing in `sscanf` is providing addresses in which to store the scanned data: `weekday` and `month` are strings, so a reference to `weekday` rather than `*weekday` is just using the address rather than the value. Since `day` and `year` are `int`s rather than `int*`s, you need to use the ampersand to provide the address.

The data type of `&day` is `int*`.

Answer (score 1):

you misunderstand. `&` gets the address of something, i.e. `&date` returns a pointer to date.

Answer (score 1):

In this example you are passing the address of the variable to the function. In this way the function is able to modify the content of the variable.

In particular, sscanf, parses the string in input and writes a value to the indicated address.

Answer (score 0):

In above case Day and Year are values, so its required & for storing value, but week and month's are address (i.e weekday == weekday[0])  so & symbol not required.